# Postgres: expand JSON array elements into values with their index?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with a column containing a JSON array. As an example:

```
with example as (
    select '["a", "b"]'::jsonb as col
    union select ('["c", "d", "e"]'::jsonb) as col
)
select col from example
```

Returns:

```
col
["a", "b"]
["c", "d", "e"]
```

I can use `jsonb_array_elements` to expand out each array into rows:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(col) from example
```

Returns:

```
jsonb_array_elements
"a"
"b"
"c"
"d"
"e"
```

I want the index of each array element along with the element itself (a bit like Python's [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate)), like so:

```
jsonb_array_elements    array_index
"a"                     1
"b"                     2
"c"                     1
"d"                     2
"e"                     3
```

How can I do this?

My application has read-only access, so I cannot create functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `with ordinality`:

```
with example (col) as (
  values 
    ('["a", "b"]'::jsonb),  
    ('["c", "d", "e"]'::jsonb)
)
select t.*
from example, jsonb_array_elements(col) with ordinality as t(e,idx)
```

returns:

```
e   | idx
----+----
"a" |   1
"b" |   2
"c" |   1
"d" |   2
"e" |   3
```

`with ordinality` can only be used if you use the set returning function in the `from` clause, which is highly recommended anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh that's an interesting little postgres puzzle. How about the below?

```
   WITH example1 AS (
        SELECT '["a", "b"]'::jsonb AS col

    ),
    example2 AS (
        SELECT ('["c", "d", "e"]'::jsonb) AS col
    )

    SELECT  1 AS group, jsonb_array_elements(col) AS jcol, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY jsonb_array_elements(col)) FROM example1
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS group, jsonb_array_elements(col) AS jcol, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY jsonb_array_elements(col)) FROM example2
    ORDER BY "group", row_number ASC;
```

That will give you

```
1   "a" 1
1   "b" 2
2   "c" 1
2   "d" 2
2   "e" 3
```